# How to set routing between nginx locations based on regex with wildcard

Tags: regex, nginx, wildcard

I have some http api behind nginx, and i want to make filter requests to API based on requests parameters value. Parameters are passed directly in url like

```
https://api.com/api/v1/action?param1=value1&param2=value2&etc...
```

Lets assume that i want to filter requests with some value of param2 to some other url.
I thought that it will be easy like

```
location ~* /api/.*param2=somevalue.* { @location; }
```

But nginx cant find the match even if there is no alternative location at all.

I'm confused. Are these wildcards are truly wildcards, or I miss something? But what?
I already tried escaping and different modifiers but no luck. :(

Comment: The `location` directive checks a [normalised URI](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) which does not include the query string.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer showed my that my approach will be invalid from the begining. I should have use conditional routing by $arg_*variable*/